# android edittext in a custom notification layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

The idea is to show in a custom notification layout a phone number , if the phone number is ok then the user accepts the phone number and the pending intent is launched with that phone number. Otherwise the user has the option to edit the phone number on the same notification and accept once the number is correct . Is it possible to do this with a custom notification layout ? Which API versions support this type of notifications ?

[image]

Comment: You cannot use an` EditText` in a RemoteViews object. The set of allowed views is listed on this page: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout

Comment: What about the quick reply in whatsapp messages?

Comment: That's implemented some other way.

Comment: Do you know in which way?

Comment: Your google search is as good as mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Karakuri is right. But Android announced new version Android N. Android N supports inline reply.

Adding inline action .

1. Create an instance of RemoteInput.Builder that you can add to your notification action. This class's constructor accepts a string that the system uses as the key for the text input. Later, your handheld app uses that key to retrieve the text of the input.

> ```
> // Key for the string that's delivered in the action's intent.
> private static final String KEY_TEXT_REPLY = "key_text_reply";
> String replyLabel = getResources().getString(R.string.reply_label);
> RemoteInput remoteInput = new RemoteInput.Builder(KEY_TEXT_REPLY)
>         .setLabel(replyLabel)
>         .build();
> ```

2. Attach the RemoteInput object to an action using addRemoteInput().

> ```
> // Create the reply action and add the remote input.
> Notification.Action action =
>         new Notification.Action.Builder(R.drawable.ic_reply_icon,
>                 getString(R.string.label), replyPendingIntent)
>                 .addRemoteInput(remoteInput)
>                 .build();
> ```

3. Apply the action to a notification and issue the notification.

> ```
> // Build the notification and add the action.
> Notification newMessageNotification =
>         new Notification.Builder(mContext)
>                 .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_message)
>                 .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.title))
>                 .setContentText(getString(R.string.content))
>                 .addAction(action))
>                 .build();
>
> // Issue the notification.
> NotificationManager notificationManager =
>         NotificationManager.from(mContext);
> notificationManager.notify(notificationId, newMessageNotification);
> ```

Retrieving user input from the inline reply,visit official doc:
https://developer.android.com/preview/features/notification-updates.html

**Backwards compatibility :**

> Both notification groups and remote input have been a part of the
>   Notification API since Android 5.0 (API level 21) to support Android
>   Wear devices. If you've already built notifications with these APIs,
>   the only action you must take is to verify that the app behavior
>   corresponds to the guidelines described above, and to consider
>   implementing setRemoteInputHistory().
>
> In order to support backward compatibility, the same APIs are
>   available with the support library's NotificationCompat class,
>   allowing you to build notifications that works on earlier Android
>   versions. On handhelds and tablets, users only see the summary
>   notification, so an app should still have an inbox style or an
>   equivalent notification representative for the whole information
>   content of the group. As Android Wear devices allow users to see all
>   child notifications even on older platform levels, you should build
>   child notifications regardless of API level.

Comment: Thanks @USKMobility , do you know any other alternative to versions prior to android N ?

Comment: This api also provide the backword compatibility.

Comment: There seems to no backward compatibility. In devices before Anroid N, text box does not appear after clicking the action button. Can anyone confirm?